# dijit.form.ValidationTextBox calls validator function twice onBlur

Tags: ajax, dojo

I have an AJAX call to check the availability of username using Dojo and PHP. Everything is working great, but there is something huge happening behind. Every time I type a word or during onBlur event, dojo makes AJAX call twice and sometimes thrice. I read this [link](http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/pipermail/dojo-checkins/2009-January/053506.html) and they say it is fixed since v1.3, I am using v1.7. I tried putting the AJAX function inside `setTimeout()` and put a 3 secs delay but still the same thing happens. How can prevent that and do only one AJAX call?

```
var _username = new dijit.form.ValidationTextBox({
name : "{{ username.name }}",
type : "text",
required : true,
invalidMessage : message.invalid.username
}, "{{ username.id }}");

dijit.byId("{{ username.id }}").validator = fnUsernameAvailable;

function fnUsernameAvailable(a) {
if (a === "" )
    return false;

dojo.xhrPost({
    url : "{{ site_url() }}/ajax/check_username_availability",
    handleAs: "json",
    content : {
        username : a,
        csrf_libtracking : fnCsrf()
    },
    load : function(data) {
        _isAvailable = data.result;
    }
});

return _isAvailable;
}
```

Comment: This may not have anything to do with your problem, but I think you won't get anything in _isAvailable since your xhrPost is async. You may add sync:true to make it synchronized, but you'd better use dojo.when or dojo.then...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a little trick like :

inside you ValidationTextBox, add a property :

```
var _username = new dijit.form.ValidationTextBox({
_beingChecked: false,
name : "{{ username.name }}",
type : "text",
required : true,
invalidMessage : message.invalid.username
}, "{{ username.id }}");

function fnUsernameAvailable(a) {
if (a === "" || this._beingChecked)
    return false;

this._beingChecked = true;

dojo.xhrPost({
    url : "{{ site_url() }}/ajax/check_username_availability",
    handleAs: "json",
    content : {
        username : a,
        csrf_libtracking : fnCsrf()
    },
    load : dojo.hitch(this, function(data) {
//        _isAvailable = data.result; <-- is this really useful ?
        this._beingChecked = false;
        dojo.publish("some/topic/to/tell/widgets/it/is/done", [data.result]);
    })
});
}
```

then somewhere in your code, or in your widget you dojo.subscribe to the topic, so that when something is published, you run a function ?

Comment: Thanks for this. I am not familiar with `dojo.hitch, dojo.subscribe and dojo.publish` yet. Better to read first before commenting again. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. My original plan was to contact the server, check if username is available, via AJAX, and return the `var _isAvailable` to trigger the `invalidMessage` property of the `ValidationTextBox` if the result is `false`. This would also trigger the tooltip to appear beside the textbox which I wanted to happen.

Pardon for my little knowledge on `dojo` as this is my first time using this framework.